# Why does compiling Wireshark from source fail?

Tags: build, compiler-errors, wireshark

I have been following this documentation to compile Wireshark from source:

http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChSetupWin32.html

I am running these commands from going to Start > 'All Programs' > Visual Studio 2008 > Visual Studio Tools > Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt

I am also calling "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat" but I believe this may be done for me with the VS2008 Command Prompt.

Here is the output of my `nmake -f Makefile.nmake verify_tools` :

```
Checking for required applications:
    cl: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/BIN/cl 
    link: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/BIN/link 
    nmake: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/BIN/nmake 
    mt: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v6.1/bin/mt 
    bash: /usr/bin/bash 
    bison: /usr/bin/bison 
    flex: /usr/bin/flex 
    env: /usr/bin/env 
    grep: /usr/bin/grep 
    /usr/bin/find: /usr/bin/find 
    peflags: /usr/bin/peflags 
    perl: /usr/bin/perl 
    C:\Python27\python.exe: /cygdrive/c/Python27/python.exe 
    sed: /usr/bin/sed 
    unzip: /usr/bin/unzip 
    wget: /usr/bin/wget
```

After this I continue to run the commands:

```
nmake -f Makefile.nmake setup

nmake -f Makefile.nmake distclean

nmake -f Makefile.nmake all
```

After calling the last command ('all'), The compilation runs for several minutes and comes to `tshark-tap-register.c`

```
tshark-tap-register.c(6) : error C2182: 'File' : illegal use of type 'void'
tshark-tap-register.c(6) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';'
before identifier 'STDIN'
```

It continues in this fashion, citing increasing line numbers with the same errors.  Finally, it halts, outputting :

```
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
```

If anyone has suggestions on things to try, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: What revision are you building?

Comment: I'm running an SVN update this morning to attempt this again.  I am attempting to build revision 43155 of their source.

Comment: You probably just want a stable source archive, not the current dev snapshot.

Comment: Build from stable Wireshark-1.8.0rc1 was successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are building the development snapshot out of SVN, you probably just pulled a revision that had an error somewhere that caused tshark-tap-register.c to be incorrectly generated. Both 43154 and 43155 build for me without issue.

Unless you need the bleeding-edge features in the development branch, you should in stead get the latest stable source distribution from the [Wireshark Downloads page](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) in the future.